# Как достать из js параметры которые вставляются в input-ы формы

Tags: php, html5, javascript

Есть код js [тут](http://pastebin.com/AgaCmd6b) который меняет скрытые инпуты, в зависимости от веденных данных в видимые инпуты, как на php выполнить js код, для того что бы получить значения скрытых инпутов?

Пишу парсер формы с сайта с последующей отправкой

Answer (score 1):

> как на php выполнить js код

Никак! Есть конечно js движки для различных языков, но боюсь вам нужно нечто другое.

Расскажите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать. Есть какой-то сайт в сети с формой ввода данных, и вы хотите написать парсер, который анализирует что ввел пользователь и отсылает вам нужную инфу?

Если так то у вас ничего не выйдет, разве что путем хакерских атак внедрить на их сайт js код. Если нет то расскажите подробнее что хотите сделать?